# How to avoid multiple rows from a join query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my SQL query. If the fbkWeightMaster has multiple records for the same patient, it returns multiple rows in the result. I want to avoid it. I tried using Distinct, but did not work.

I confirmed that the issue occurs when there are multiple entries in fbkWeightMaster table from the below query.

```
Select Distinct
        a.patientid
      , a.firstname
      , a.lastname
      , a.mobile
      , a.dob
      , b.InitialWeight
      , b.LatestWeight
      , a.height
      , c.PlanName
      , a.warning
      , a.indicator
      , a.city
      , a.email
      , a.state
      , a.comments
      , a.introduction
      , a.gender
      , a.address
      , a.landline
      , a.FoodPreference
From    
    fbkPatientMaster a
Join
    fbkPlanMaster c On a.PlanID = c.PlanID
Join    
    fbkWeightMaster b On a.PatientID = b.PatientID
Join    
    fbkChartMaster d On d.PatientID = a.PatientID
Where   
    IsActive = 1
    And a.PatientID Not In (Select Distinct PatientID
                            From fbkChartMaster
                            Where Cast(ChartDate As Date) = DateAdd(Day, 1, Cast(GetDate() As Date)))
    And a.PatientID Not In (Select Distinct PatientID
                            From fbkChartHold
                            Where Cast(ChartHoldTo As Date) > Cast(GetDate() As Date));
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` works. If you get multiple rows, it's because the selected data isn't unique - some of the columns *are* different. What did you get and what did you expect? What are the table definitions and relations?

Comment: do an outer apply on a select top 1 of the patients

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I agree the overall data in the selected columns isn't unique. But the fbkWeightMaster table is suppose to have different data for same ID. If a patient named James has ten rows in that table, it should return only 1 row when that table is joined.

Comment: Please identify which table haveing Duplicate entry (exp: transsaction table)  then use subquery for Join..Like   Join (  Select Distinct Col1, Col2 From fbkWeightMaster ) fbkWeightMaster b On a.PatientID = b.PatientID

Comment: @FakhruddinKhambaty why should it? Post the schema and what you expect the data to look like. It's impossible to reproduce the issue just with the query text

Comment: Thank you everyone. The answer given by @SqlZim just solved the issue.

Comment: @Fakhruddin Khambaty, as the answer from SqlZim helped you, please show some appreciation by marking it as answer.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you really should get out of the habit of using a,b,c as aliases. Here is an excellent explanation of why it is not a good practice. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change your join to a [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) and `select top 1` from `fbkWeightMaster` according to some order, such as a `date` column. This will return only 1 row from `fbkWeightMaster` per `a.patientid`.

[**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) works similar to an `inner join` if you want the functionality you get with a `left join` use `outer apply()` instead.

```
Select 
        a.patientid
      , a.firstname
      , a.lastname
      , a.mobile
      , a.dob
      , b.InitialWeight
      , b.LatestWeight
      , a.height
      , c.PlanName
      , a.warning
      , a.indicator
      , a.city
      , a.email
      , a.state
      , a.comments
      , a.introduction
      , a.gender
      , a.address
      , a.landline
      , a.FoodPreference
From    
    fbkPatientMaster a
Join
    fbkPlanMaster c On a.PlanID = c.PlanID
Join    
    fbkChartMaster d On d.PatientID = a.PatientID
cross apply (
  select top 1 *
  from fbkWeightMaster b 
  where a.PatientID = b.PatientID
  order by b.date desc
) b

Where   
    IsActive = 1
    And a.PatientID Not In (Select Distinct PatientID
                            From fbkChartMaster
                            Where Cast(ChartDate As Date) = DateAdd(Day, 1, Cast(GetDate() As Date)))
    And a.PatientID Not In (Select Distinct PatientID
                            From fbkChartHold
                            Where Cast(ChartHoldTo As Date) > Cast(GetDate() As Date));
```

Comment: @FakhruddinKhambaty: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.